# HP iLO CPQCIDRV not found when module is loaded

Tags: ubuntu, hp, hp-proliant, ilo, out-of-band-management

I'm trying to connect to the iLO interface on my HP ProLiant Server. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

I've been following instructions including

- [https://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/project/mcp/](https://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/project/mcp/])
- https://www.vcloudnine.de/reset-the-hp-ilo-administrator-password-with-hponcfg-on-esxi/
- https://blog.tinned-software.net/set-the-ilo-password-from-linux-using-hponcfg/

When I install the hponcfg package and run the command `hpilo`, I get the following message:

```
HP Lights-Out Online Configuration utility
Version 5.3.0 Date 3/21/2018 (c) 2005,2018 Hewlett Packard Enterprise Development LP

ERROR: CpqCiCreateFunc() 0 time failed.
Driver Error Code:(1,1h).
Driver Error Message: CPQCIDRV driver is not loaded.

ERROR: CpqCiCreateFunc() 1 time failed.
Driver Error Code:(1,1h).
Driver Error Message: CPQCIDRV driver is not loaded.
ERROR:  Could not find the Management Processor Device Node.
        Please check if the iLO driver module is installed and running properly.
        ACTION REQUIRED: Install/Re-install hp Lights-Out driver package('hp-ilo' RPM) for iLO.
```

The output of `lsmod | grep hpilo` is: `hpilo                  20480  0`

Do you have any ideas what might be the cause?

Thanks.